# How to organize protocol implementations phoenix

Tags: phoenix-framework, multi-select, organization

The title might be misleading for my specific question, but I want to implement `Phoenix.HTML.Safe` for maps for multi-select in the views to accomplish the following.

given the schema:

```
schema "customers" do
    field :owners, {:array, :integer}, virtual: true
    many_to_many :users, User,
                         join_through: CustomerUser,
                         on_delete: :delete_all
end
```

I want to select `owners` of the customer account from a list of users.

So controller query would be something like:

```
customer = Customer
           |> Repo.get!(id)
           |> Repo.preload(:users)
```

And the view / multi-select would look something like:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= multiple_select f, 
                        :owners, 
                        Enum.map(@customer.users, fn(u)-> %{u.email => u.id} end), 
                        class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

But this throws:

> protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for %{"hulk@hogan.com" => 2}

So, if I implement the `Phoenix.HTML.safe` protocol for maps where should this code live... `lib`?

Comment: Try `Enum.map(@customer.users, fn(u) -> {u.email, u.id} end)`.

Comment: If you look at the docs for `multiple_select` you will see that it takes a *list* of tuples as @dogbert suggests. You are providing a list of maps.

Comment: Thanks gents. I guess my question still stands, however. If I were to implement the protocol for something I'd like available in all of my views, where should that code live?

Comment: Just to be clear, defining a protocol for map will not work here since the api expects a list strings, atoms, or tuples. With that said, you can put a `defimpl` in a .ex file anywhere. I typically put them in the lib folder. Also note that `defimpl` does **not** go in a module.

Comment: Thank you Steve... again! And yes, I'm aware of your first point (I implemented it and saw it in action). If either you or @dogbert want to submit an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks gents!